# "No Launchpad project set" - Quickly

Tags: application-development, launchpad, quickly

I want to get a project on Launchpad using Quickly, but if I run `quickly submitubuntu` it just tells me that `No Launchpad project set, leave blank to abort.`. If I enter the name of my project he tells me that there is no project.

Comment: what is the name of your project on Launchpad?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to upload your project to launchpad, you must have the SSH key of your computer recognized by your launchpad account, a ppa set up for your project, your openPGP key recognized by launchpad, and then you must run `quickly share` or `quickly release`. It should connect to launchpad, allow you to specify the ppa where you wish to upload, then upload it. I had problems similar to yours yesterday, then I found out I had to make launchpad recognize my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://launchpad.net/projects/+new and register your project. After that run "quickly submitubuntu"

Answer (score 0):

I think that `quickly submitubuntu` is a command to submit an application, not to get it. To get an application which is on launchpad, you need to go on the project page, and download the debian package of the project.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to register your own project on launchpad. Do this [here](https://launchpad.net/projects/+new).

You have to setup a SSH key and sign it. You can do this on your launchpad home screen.

When your application is registered, you can start uploading the app. Do this with

```
quickly submitubuntu
```

Now you can specify your project and start submitting.