# "No Launchpad project set" when running "quickly submitubuntu"

Tags: quickly

I have seen the posting [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156707/no-launchpad-project-set-quickly) which is regarding the same issue, but the responses were not useful in solving my problem.

I am able to generate my package, as well as release it to my PPA with the "quickly release" command, but I have been unable to get the "submitubuntu" command to work.

```
quickly submitubuntu
Get Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
No Launchpad project set, leave blank to abort.
Launchpad project name:
```

No matter what I enter for the project name, nothing works. I have my ssh keys and all that set up, and I was even able to upload directly to launchpad with the "quickly release" command...

The reason I want the "submitubuntu" command to work, is because I am doing this application for the ubuntu app showdown, and it needs to run from /opt, which according to [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/) as well as the rules, can be accomplished via the "submitubuntu" command.

----edit----

I did not know there was a difference between a project and a PPA, and it looks like the submitubuntu command will only work with a project.

I created a project, and ran the command and it submitted successfully to the project and the PPA, but I could not associate the PPA with the project because it said the source was not for precise, though when I looked at the details for all of the packages, it said they were for precise...

Additionally, the submitted packages are failing to build.

Will continue to post info as it works out (or doesnt).

https://help.launchpad.net/Projects/Registering

Answer (score 2):

I was having a dependency error which I worked around by using the steps in the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu).

In my case, it was easier to manually update the ppa, so if you are having issues with your source.changes being rejected or failing to be compiled by launchpad from a "submitubuntu" command, consider following the post linked above.